# Include not working (noobie)

Tags: php, html, php-include

So my include PHP tag is not working for some reason. (I do have wamp server installed, so i can open .php files in browser)

index.php:

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>

 </head>
<body style="background-color: #292727;">

<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
  include('header.php');
?>




</body>
</html>
```

header.php:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
echo '  <div class="top_bar">

</div>

<div class="header_gif">
    <div class="header_overlay">    
    </div>
</div>

<div class="sponsor_bar">

</div>

<div class="navigation_bar">
    <div class="nav_container">
        <a href="index.php"><div class="nav_bar_box" id="home">HOME</div></a>
        <a href="index.php"><div class="nav_bar_box" id="brackets">BRACKETS</div></a>
        <a href="index.php"><div class="nav_bar_box" id="teams">TEAMS</div></a>
        <a href="index.php"><div class="nav_bar_box" id="news">NEWS</div></a>
        <a href="index.php"><div class="nav_bar_box" id="info">INFO</div></a>
    </div>
</div>'; 
?>
```

They are in the same folder. Do you have any idea why its not working?

Comment: [You tell us...](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Comment: What Fred is trying to say is that you can set PHP to display errors if it fails to load anything. Check his link.

Comment: Is that the entire code of your scripts?

Comment: Your claim that "I can open .php files in browser" worries me. Are you opening `file:///C:\Users\Ricma357\Documents\wwwroot\index.php` or `http://localhost/index.php`?

Comment: ^ Niet's got a point ^

Comment: I will put my full code in answer because it will be too long for this.

Comment: Quick way to check if PHP is working at all: right-click and select "View Source" (or similar). If you see your PHP source there, then it's not running.

Comment: Another thing; on certain systems `Header.php` is not the same as `header.php`, so check your file's lettercase. Too many things can be a factor here.

Comment: Please put the code in your question also if it is so long then debug it yourself until you get the error separated. Or just show as a few lines above and under this also which the error you get

Comment: I do see my php code in red letters when i "view source". What can cause that?

Comment: You haven't responded to any of the comments above.

Comment: Im opening it `file:///C:/wamp/www/Rework%20E-spotd2c/premium/index.php`

Like that.

Comment: Well there's your problem ^^^^^ use `http://localhost/path/to/file.php`

Comment: You have to call your file over the server! So something like: `localhost/index.php`

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol You have the floor. Care for an answer on [that comment of yours](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27638157/include-not-working-noobie#comment43695093_27638157)? ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just having a _AMP stack installed does not magically make files load as PHP if you open them directly in your browser - they have to actually go through the server to be processed.

Consequently, this is wrong:

```
file:///C:/wamp/www/Rework%20E-spotd2c/premium/index.php
```

Something like this would be right: (depending on the server's document root setting)

```
http://localhost/index.php
```

An additional note that may be helpful, for people developing with PHP 5.4 or newer, is the built-in server. Open a command line to the folder you want to use as the root (such as your project folder), and run the following command:

```
php -S localhost:8000
```

You can now go to `http://localhost:8000/index.php` in your browser and PHP will run! I use this all the time for testing stuff locally. To shut down the server, simply Ctrl+C the command window. You can also use `php -S 192.168.0.128:8000` (put your LAN IP there) to let other users on your network access your test server stuff too, great for showing off to coworkers ;)

Comment: Thank you for the info, ill try that now and let you know how it goes!

Comment: *"Just having a MAMP stack"* - OP's using Wamp ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Right letter, just upside-down XD Changed to `_AMP` since the platform doesn't really matter.

Comment: Its working after i put `http://localhost/e-spotd2c/premium/`! Thanks man :) (i renamed the folder)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Hahaha! You're right. When I rotated my head 180 degrees vertically, all was fine, well... almost ;-) *Cheers*